# If I have an exponential likelihood and a normal prior for the exponential mean, what is the form of the posterior?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, posterior, exponential-distribution

Suppose I have an exponential likelihood and a normal prior for the exponential mean, what is the form of the posterior density?

Comment: A normal prior wouldn't make sense to me because the mean is necessarily positive, while any normal assigns some probability to negative values. A truncated normal might make some sense, but would end up giving the same result ... How does the question arise? Is it a question for some subject, for example?

Comment: Just to double check that I correctly understand your intent - the exponential model for the observations is the scale-parameterization rather than the rate-parameterization? (I ask because the rate parameterization looks much simpler to deal with.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an outline of the case with a truncated Gaussian prior (but on the assumption that this might be a self-study problem, I'll leave it as an outline for now).

1. If we have the rate parameterization, let's call the parameter for the exponential rate $\lambda$.

   The exponent in a truncated Gaussian prior is quadratic in $\lambda$. The exponent in the likelihood is linear in $\lambda$. Expanding the quadratic and combining the exponents then completing the square yields a truncated Gaussian posterior.
2. If you're dealing with the scale parameterization (which is what I think you intended with the framing of your question), let's call the parameter for the exponential scale $\mu$.

   Then the likelihood and the prior are not "compatible", you end up with terms in the exponent in $\mu^2$, $\mu$ and $\mu^{-1}$ and off the top of my head I don't recognize a distribution with all three terms as having a particular name.

---

An untruncated Gaussian prior follows essentially the same reasoning, also giving a truncated Gaussian posterior in the first case and the same three terms that I mention above in the second case. In fact if you use indicator functions the difference in doing them is trivial.